# Input power protection for PAN4820

Tags: power, emi-filtering, line

We want to design a telecom compatible power entry circuit with 48V 20A rating for a student project (design of a telecom equipment with 48V DC input power) using PAN4820 devices.

The schematic diagram of the design is attached. All parts are rated for 200V.

The problem is that in the PAN4820 datasheet, the test voltage is 100V but in our design MOVs’ maximum clamping voltage is around 165V.

I would like to know whether PAN4820 supports surge voltages around 160V for short periods of time (8/20us) or not. I could not find such a thing in the filter’s datasheet.

Thanks in advance[image]

Comment: hm, did you already incorporate your spark gaps, MOVs and TVS diodes into this consideration?

Comment: Unknown BUT the 100v spec is **"Test voltage between terminals for 1 minute".** [Datasheet here](https://www.oemsec.com/datasheet/d9/PAN4820.pdf).  || New MOVs sounds like a good idea.

Comment: also, but that might be my ignorance: shouldn't the fuses be on the voltage source side of the MOVs?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon Correct, 100V test voltage is mentioned in device datasheet (as noted in the question). 
If we consider allowed voltage to be in 36-60V range, MOVs which work at this range also have high clamping voltages. For example, MOV-20D820K is rated for 65V continuous but its clamping voltage is 136V (unfortunately higher than 100V).
If there is a candidate MOV working in this range, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It is rated for 76V and 100V absolute Max verified  1 min. @ 100Vdc.
The susceptibility to 8/20us surge test for ionization tolerance is much higher than 50 Hz or DC and is perhaps double between enamelled copper windings YET not mentioned.  I believe lightning tests are common-mode around 6kV to 10kV, while Hipot is under 1kV CM, 100V diff.

So the question is how well balanced and what is the impedance ratio and CMRR from line to load that would impart a differential or leg to the ground voltage from common-mode induced lightning. ( it won't survive a direct hit differential mode but is also unlikely.)

165V TVS is good for ESD yet we know ESD from 100pF into x Ohms TVS has rise time in ns.

But if you are getting it certified to certain EU standards, that's beyond my paygrade which is 0 in retirement near Toronto.

Comment: He's attempting to protect the actual line filter - which has a leg-leg operating voltage of 60V and an abs max 1 minute voltage of 100V. That SUGGESTS that a 165V clamping MOV would PROBABLY be OK BUT maybe not.

Answer (score 0):

**Summary:**

- It is reasonably likely that the filter will survive the short overvoltage spike for a maximum energy surge, and the manufacturer will be able to advise.
- The 820k may better meet your needs if the slightly lower 1 mA drain voltage is tolerable in practice.
- Note in Tony's answer the fact that the line to ground voltage is liable to be higher than line to line true common mode and so in such cases the line to ground MOVs will handle surges while still; within filter voltage ratings.

---

Here is an expanded version of the relevant portion of the performance graph from the [**datasheet**](https://www.bourns.com/docs/Product-Datasheets/MOV20D.pdf).

The MOV-20D101K is the blue curve.
The expanded version may be (is) slightly 'off' but is close enough.
The next lowest rated 820k is the black curve below the blue curve and may be closer to your need IF the maximum voltage really matters and IF the slightly lower DC & RMs volateg at 1 mA is well enough above your normal operating voltage.
It may well be that the very short voltage spike on fault within MOV energy ratings is tolerable by the filter.
The filter manufacturer MUST know these specs and should be able to advise you.

[image]

At 110V the 101K draws about 1A, 10A at about 120V, 100A at about 145V.

[image]

**Original curves:**

[image]